# Rules to realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I use Firebase, to be precise a real-time database, and I don't know what rules should I set. I set these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
        ".read": "data.child('Users').child(auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": true
  }
}
```

but now everybody can write.
When I set these:

```
{
  "rules": {
        ".read": "data.child('Users').child(auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

users using Gmail cannot log in because record in the database isn't created but not on all devices. When i test on OnePlus every is fine, when i test on Samsung record in the database isn't created.
This is my code responsible for creating user:

```
fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(reg_email, reg_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        fAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        reg_user = new User(reg_email, sex, btn_text, 0, 0);
                        databaseReference.child(userID).setValue(reg_user);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fAuth.getCurrentUser()` may not yet be set when you're using it inside your inner callback. Instead, use the user from the outermost task to determine the UID.

```
fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(reg_email, reg_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> createTask) { //  rename here
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        fAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> verifyTask) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        userID = createTask.getResult().getUser().getUid(); //  use here
                        reg_user = new User(reg_email, sex, btn_text, 0, 0);
                        databaseReference.child(userID).setValue(reg_user);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, user is created in "Authentication" but in realtime isn't

Comment: "it doesn't work" is really hard to help with. I recommend setting breakpoints on the first line inside each `onComplete` method and running the code in a debugger. Check what the value of `createTask.getResult().getUser().getUid()` is in the second one. It might also be useful to [add a completion listener to your `setValue` call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback), to see if there's any error there.

Comment: But why this problem is on Samsung and not on OnePlus? This two metods `createTask.getResult().getUser().getUid()` and `fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()` returns the same value.